# How to clip UIView behind of View

Tags: swift

I have a view called SearchView and a vendorBlock with "lalal" label. The problem is i use searchView.backgroundColor with opacity, and when I am changing mode I see UI bug. How can I clip vendorBlock to not see part of it behind of searchView?

```
private lazy var searchView: SearchView = {
        let view = SearchView()
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        view.delegate = self
        return view
    }()
    
    private var vendorBlock: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
        view.backgroundColor = AppColors.vendorView
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        return view
    }()
```

```
private func linkLayout() {
        addSubview(vendorBlock)
        addSubview(searchView)
        
        searchView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(248)
        }
        
        vendorBlock.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(searchView.snp.bottom).inset(16)
            make.height.equalTo(46)
            make.leading.trailing.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        addSubview(vendorLabel)
        vendorLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(8)
            make.leading.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
        }
    }
```

How it has to be
[image: ez]

How it has to be
[image: example]

Bug I see
[image: darkMode]

How it has to be
[image: lightMode]

Comment: Can you show the expected output? It's unclear what is wrong with your screenshots.

Comment: updated. Could u look again on the light mode, then on the dark mode?. Also I added one more screenshot